# Reference request for Gribov ambiguity

Tags: resource-recommendations, gauge-theory, yang-mills, gauge

I was hoping to find a reference (book or article) with a good introduction to the Gribov Ambiguity in non-abelian gauge theories. I’ve looked through QFT books by Schwartz and Srednicki, Rubakov’s book on Gauge Fields as well as David Tong’s lecture notes on Gauge theory but none of them seem to talk about this. Could someone please suggest some good reference material for this topic? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best reference is Gribov's original paper [Quantization of non-Abelian gauge theories](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/055032137890175X?via%3Dihub) which discusses the topic with sufficient details. Additionally, Singer's paper [Some remarks on the Gribov ambiguity](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103904019) discusses some important theorems associated with Grimov ambiquity, though the paper is mathematically terse.

A recent review is [The Gribov problem and QCD dynamics](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.1491.pdf) which is quite detailed and is a pedagogic introduction to Gribov's approach and the succeeding construction of the so-called Gribov–Zwanziger action.