# A reference request on fundamental modular domains in the context of Gribov ambiguity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, gauge-theory, yang-mills, gauge

I see that there are some references in the post [PE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/482274/) on the Gribov ambiguity.

However, resolution of this ambiguity, as stated in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gribov_ambiguity), is to find the fundamental modular region (FMR).

I looked into the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_domain#Fundamental_domain_for_the_modular_group) dealing with fundamental domains of modular groups. However, it does not seem to focus on the non-Abelian gauge theories.

Could anyone please suggest any reference focusing on the methods / discussions of finding a fundamental modular region to resolve the Gribov ambiguity for Yang-Mills theories?